# Scala non-generic collection

Tags: scala, scala-collections, generic-collections

In Scala 2.10.2, I'm creating a class `MultiLogger`, which will inherit from `scala.sys.process.ProcessLogger`, providing logging multiplexing.

My idea for the class looks a bit like this:

```
class MultiLogger[T <: ProcessLogger]
(
    private val loggers : Set[T]
)
    extends Set[T]
    with scala.collection.SetLike[T,Set[T]]
    with scala.sys.ProcessLogger
{
...
}
```

It may as well look like a set of `ProcessLogger` objects, since that's effectively what it is.

The problem comes when I try to define the companion object which provides `NewBuilder`, e.g.:

```
object MultiLogger extends ImmutableSetFactory[MultiLogger]
{
    override def newBuilder[T]() : Builder[T, MultiLogger[T]] = new Builder[T, MultiLogger[T]]
    {
        var elems = Set[T]()
        def +=( t : T ) = { elems = elems + t; this } 
        def clear() { elems = elems.empty }
        def result() : MultiLogger[T] = new MultiLogger( elems ) // ERROR HERE
    }
}
```

This then complains that the `T` in `newBuilder` doesn't conform to the type requirements of `MultiLogger`, unsurprisingly.

What's the way around this? Should I not use the `ImmutableSetFactory` at all, and just roll my own constructors (it would work, but it's not going to look as nice, and will require thought and testing!) or is there a non-generic set factory which I don't know about?

Comment: The first class doesn't type-check. Where does `T` come from?

Comment: Would the `T` in `newBuilder` not need to be `<: ProcessLogger`?

Comment: Yes, but then it doesn't conform to the type of `newBuilder`

Answer (score 0):

`ImmutableSetFactory` is in fact only for generic collections, as hinted at by its package (`scala.collection.generic`), and seen in its type:

```
abstract class ImmutableSetFactory[CC[X] <: immutable.Set[X]
                                            with SetLike[X, CC[X]]]
  extends SetFactory[CC]
```

The `CC` parameter must generic, not just generic with restrictions, because it must accept any type `X` as its parameter.

However, there is very little code, and only one constructor, actually implemented for you by using this, in the short source files [ImmutableSetFactory.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.2/src/library/scala/collection/generic/ImmutableSetFactory.scala), [GenericCompanion.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.2/src/library/scala/collection/generic/GenericCompanion.scala), and [GenSetFactory.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.2/src/library/scala/collection/generic/GenSetFactory.scala).

A better starting point than `ImmutableSetFactory` might be reading [The Architecture of Scala Collections](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/architecture-of-scala-collections.html). The RNA strand example is a non-generic `Seq`, so while it's not a `Set`, it shows that the collections library is more than capable of being used for non-generic collections.

Comment: The first reason this code should not compile is that `MultiLogger` doesn't conform to the type constraints of `ImmutableSetFactory`'s type parameters.